# Is "recent past" an oxymoron?

Tags: oxymoron

I saw "recent past" included in a page of supposed oxymorons posted on Facebook, with people yukking it up while apparently badly misunderstanding what an oxymoron is. One well-meaning but confused gentleman pointed me to a link to a different page also claiming that "recent past" is an oxymoron.

This seems ultra-simple to me: the two words have to be in apparent conflict, but they're simply not. I tried to give a helpful example (having gone to the store yesterday) but think the people arguing with me may still not understand.

Am I wrong?

Comment: If recent cannot be in the present or future, when would recent things occur if not the past, but, er, the recent past? You are not wrong, you are right.

Comment: You are right.  Exactly what is the recent past depends on what you are talking about and your perspective.  It could be yesterday, or it could be years ago.   In the recent past -- pre-Google -- we had to look up everything in books.  Recent to me, Dark Ages to someone else.  Also note that the past could be one second ago.  One picosecond ago.  Even less.

Comment: Maybe, perhaps, you might considerer that as redundant within some special context. In general, that's not even redundant, only more explicit. The past that you are referring to can be distant, one million years ago, or recent, only a few years ago. How is this redundant or oxymoronic?  Occam's razor: Some people don't understand the words they are using, such as oxymoron.

Comment: In fact, in English we don't say "recent future", we say [***near*** *future*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/in-the-near-future) and [*in the not too* ***distant*** *future*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/distant). And would they find the following phrase oxymoronic: "D.Trump ***recently visited*** France."

Comment: I think it _could_ be considered a pleonasm rather than an oxymoron, based on the fact that something that happened _recently_ obviously happened in the past, the issue not being about recently modifying past but rather about _past_ being applied while we already know an event was in the past because of the presence of _recent_. This would, imho, only make sense if _recent_ could be used instead of _recent past_, which it can't.

Comment: In fact only things that are in the past can be described as "recent."

Comment: Why does this have so many upvotes?  'recent' and 'past' are not even opposites.

Comment: @Alex Sarmiento: But if you're discussing geology or paleontology, a million years IS the recent past :-)

Comment: Of course it's not an oxymoron. perhaps a definition would be good, but 'recent past' will never be an oxymoron. Only a moron would think so...

Comment: The real oxymoron is intelligent facebook discussion...

Comment: "Jumbo shrimp" is not really a contradiction, e.g, because "shrimp" refers to the animal rather than size. It shows up on every canonical list of oxymorons because, as a play on words, it's funny anyway. It seems like your complaint is that "recent past" isn't a very funny oxymoron. Opinions vary.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Regarding "the not too distant future," would next Sunday, AD qualify?

Comment: Your question raises another in my mind. What do you mean by "people yukking it up"? In sixty years (I'm British) I've never heard this expression.

Comment: @Nicole HTH :) http://lmgtfy.com/?q=yuk+it+up

Comment: @Iucounu Ahh. Now I understand. It's regional dialect.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/recent-past#:~:text=adjective%20%5Busually%20ADJECTIVE%20noun%5D,only%20a%20short%20while%20ago.) gives a headed entry and example sentences. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/recent-past) gives the collocation with many examples. // 'Recently in the past' is a **tautology**, but 'recent past' is a 'proper subset' of 'past'.

Comment: An oxymoron is often defined as something that's *superficially* or *at first glance* a paradox or self-contradictory. Many things are very superficially paradoxes in this sense, e.g. "He's a little tall", "It's pretty ugly".

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No. You are correct. It is both common and acceptable to qualify **the past** as **the distant past** or **the recent past**.

Comment: You aren't wrong, but this answer would be much stronger with any kind of evidence or sources. I doubt a bare assertion is going to do it for the folks who genuinely think this *is* an oxymoron.

Comment: @1006a, OP said this came out of a Facebook post.  Have you ever tried to convince someone on Facebook they were wrong?  No amount of evidence or sources will help.  :)

Comment: @tilper I didn't mean the OP's nemeses, I meant anyone who is genuinely wondering and turns to ELU for a definitive answer. We're supposed to be creating answers that are generally applicable/helpful, not just reassuring a single asker that what he/she already knew is correct. Even a few dictionary definitions would be a big improvement, and a few lines of text explaining how those definitions apply to this phrase would be great.

Comment: I do believe I left a comment earlier this morning asking the OP to consider explaining why, but for some mysterious reason, users must have flagged it and it was deleted.

Comment: I agree that sources would help. I couldn't think of them at the time and still can't; as I recall I was answering from the usage I'm familiar with. We say _distant future_ and _distant past_, and we say _near future_ but _recent past_. So, dear community, edit some useful stuff into my answer and I'll mark it community-wiki.

Answer (score 17):

You are correct about usage: it is not an oxymoron, because "recent" and "past" are not in opposition.  The word "past" in that phrase is, to an extent, *redundant*.  An oxymoron would be an instance of two words whose meanings suggest each other's opposite, or at least significantly dissimilar concepts.  As a comment suggests, a phrase containing some redundancy such as "recent past" might be called a *pleonasm*, though I don't think it's a common term in regular conversation.

Comment: It's not redundant.

Comment: @Clare How can something that happened "recently" ever not be in the past?  Please don't mistake my use of the term "redundant" to imply "incorrect" - the phrase is a common one that I use myself and there is certainly *more* information provided by putting the words together.  I'm just suggesting that some of the information in the word *past* is already implied by the word *recent* - hence, some redundancy.  Regardless, I have edited my answer for some clarification and less strong wording.

Comment: Being redundant is where I would've taken my answer as well.

Comment: It's not redundant because you can't talk about the past with just the word *recent*, and you can't distinguish between the *recent past* and the *distant past* without the word *recent*. Just like *near future* and *distant future* are also not redundant. How will you talk about the *near future* without using both words, and still fully specify what you mean? I think you might be a little confused...

Comment: @ErikE Well I can assure you, there is no confusion here.  It's not *entirely* redundant but there is absolutely redundancy in it.

Comment: @DarrenRinger You could address the points I made and explain how the words which I attempted to show are not redundant actually are, by expressing the same concept without using both the words (or synonyms of them). I used a reasoned argument, not mere assertion.

Comment: Okay, if I say, "I went to the store recently," it is clearly an event that happened in the past.  Thus, "I went to the store in the recent past" is a redundant way of saying "I went to the store recently".  When I said "There is clearly more information provided by putting the words together" I was referring to the equivalent of adding "-ly" to "recent" (more than that, but I'm trying to keep this explanation simple).

Comment: Also, "future" does not imply "near" and "near" does not imply "future" but "recent" always implies "past".

Comment: "Recently" is a different word. It's an adverb, not an adjective. This is new information you didn't include in your post. I call foul! "Recently past" *would* be redundant because "recently" contains all the information that "recently past" does. But "recent" does not contain all the information that "recent past" does. Try: "I went to the store recent." I agree that using one word is more *succinct*, but that doesn't make it redundant. (I can say "Clown A is more funny" or "Clown A is funnier" but that doesn't make the former redundant.

Comment: "Recently" doesn't imply "past" any more than "recent" does.  If someone said "I went to the store recent" I would know what they meant just as well as if they were to say "I went to the store in the recent past".  I can't imagine any confusion that would be clarified by either choice of words.

Comment: @ErikE: *Semantically*, "recent past" is redundant, because "past" isn't supplying any further information beyond what "recent" supplies. "Past" is only needed because it fills a *syntactic* role. When another noun fills that role, "past" is not needed: hence e.g. "in recent weeks" (no need for "in past recent weeks" or "in recent weeks past" or whatnot).

Comment: "The recent events in Oceania..." would be another example to show how "recent" can be used sensibly without requiring "past".  Also, I would not consider "recent" and "recently" to be entirely different words; they are different forms of the same word. They have the same core meaning and differ only in the way they are allowed to be used with other words.

Comment: ErikE is bang on the money. It is not redundant at all. 'Recent events' and 'the recent past' do not have the same meaning at all, and neither does the 'the recent past' and 'recently'. The 'past' is necessary to define what is referred to. One could imagine an alternate English in which we say 'the recent' to mean 'the recent past' but that is not how the language actually works.

Comment: @JackAidley: What about "Recent events" and "events in the recent past"? To me both phrases have identical meaning.  And even if your rulebooks of formally recognized grammar do not recognize "the recent" as meaning "the recent past", you'll find that based on how language in general works, most people find both to be synonymous.

Comment: @DarrenRinger: To me "recent events" would refer to events much closer in the past than "events in the recent past", although the meaning of both is subject to context.

Comment: I find it quite entertaining that a supposed oxymoron comes out as a pleonasm instead. People should be more aware of pleonasms, as they are much more important lexically than oxymora.

Comment: @IllidanS4: I think most people know them as tautologies rather than pleonasms?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why it is wrong to modify the noun past with the adjective recent.
It conveys to me the idea of a time neither recent nor in the remote or undetermined past but somewhere in between.

Answer (score 0):

"recent past" as compared to "distant past".

Both are "past", but "recent" is closer to present than "distant". So both "recent" and "distant" are valid qualifiers for "past", so not an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what a facebook is but but it must have been written by morons if it says that 'recent past' is an oxymoron.  As you are no doubt aware, Italian names two past tenses with the recent and distant (historic) distinction: *passato remoto* and *passato prossimo*.